# What is the Task equivalent to Promise.then()?

Tags: c#, .net, typescript, async-await

With the addition of async / await to TypeScript using Promise(s) can look very syntactically close to Task(s).

Example:

Promise (TS)

```
public async myAsyncFun(): Promise<T> {
    let value: T = await ...
    return value;
}
```

Task (C#)

```
public async Task<T> MyAsyncFun() {
    T value = await ...
    return value;
}
```

I was wondering if the other way around, there was an equivalent to .then() for Task(s).

Example:

Promise (TS)

```
Promise<T> promise = ...
promise.then((result: T) => ...do something...);
```

Comment: Look at `Task` continuations (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288(v=vs.110).aspx). There are also some other interesting methods such as the `When...()` and `Wait...()` methods (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've used `ContinueWith` which can work if you have one or multiple Tasks running.

example:

```
public async Task<T> MyAsyncFun() {
    T value = await ...
    return value;
}

MyAsyncFun().ContinueWith(...
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So would it look like: 
`Task<T> task = await ...
task.ContinueWith((task, result) => ...do something...);`

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you, Sorry I submitted my first comment without finishing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a handy extension method for task continuations to match the javascript `.then` function. I find it easier to use than `.ContinueWith`, which has its own set of pitfalls and encumbrances.

```cs
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static async Task<TV> Then<T,TV>(this Task<T> task, Func<T,TV> then)
    {
        var result = await task;
        return then(result);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like so

```cs
Task<User> userRecord = GetUserById(123)
Task<string> firstName = userRecord.Then(u => u.FirstName)
```

Comment: The `await task` might need to be configured with `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, or might not, depending on where you want to invoke the `then` lambda. So this is not a good operator for general use. Related GitHub API proposal: [Then or ContinueWithResult extension method for Task](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/58692).

Comment: If you care about `.ConfigureAwait`, you can add an optional parameter to the extension method.

Comment: And what would be the default value of the optional parameter?

Comment: `true` since that's the default `.ConfigureAwait` value if you choose not to use `.ConfigureAwait`

Comment: Then it would not be consistent with [the default](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Asynchronous-action-execution#synchronizationcontext) of the popular Polly library.